# Rebind Telerik TreeView with Json data from controller

Tags: c#, json, telerik, treeview

I'm using Telerik Extensions for MVC.

I have a TreeView and want to do with it:

1. Display only root elements when I open the site and load children on demand with Ajax when expanding - this works!
2. Search for nodes and then rebind the tree widh result data.

I can't get point 2 to work. Some code:

View:

```
@(Html.Telerik().TreeView()
   .Name("OuTree")
   .DataBinding(dataBinding =>
       {
           dataBinding.Ajax()
               .Enabled(true)
               .Select("NodePreview", "OrganizationalStructure");
       })
   )
```

Expand method for point 1 on controller (WORKS!)

```
public JsonResult NodePreview(int? Value)
    {
        int nodeId = Value.HasValue == false ? 0 : Value.Value;
        var request = OrganizationTreeNodeRequestCreate(nodeId);
        var service = _ProductSetupService;
        var response = service.OrganizationTreeNodeGet(request);

        var tree = from ou in response.Children
                   select new
                   {
                       Value = ou.Id,
                       Text = ou.OrganizationUnit.Name,
                       LoadOnDemand = ou.Subordinates.Count > 0
                   };
        return Json(tree, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

Now the hard part.
I want to be able to search for nodes and then rebind the tree with result data.
I already have a search service that returns hierarchical structure. Problem is with binding.

Controller action for point 2:

```
public JsonResult Search(SearchModel model)
    {
        var request = OrganizationTreeSearchRequestCreate(model);
        var service = _ProductSetupService;
        var response = service.OrganizationTreeSearch(request);

        var treeViewItem = new TreeViewItem();
        treeViewItem.BindTo(response.Results, mappings =>
            {
                mappings.For<OrganizationUnitTree>(binding => binding
                    .ItemDataBound((item, group) =>
                    {
                        item.Text = group.OrganizationUnit.Name;
                        item.Value = group.Id.ToString();
                        item.LoadOnDemand = true;
                    })
                    .Children(group => group.Subordinates));
            });

        return Json(treeViewItem, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

    }
```

Then on the client side:

```
function ReloadTree(data) {
var treeview = $('#OuTree').data('tTreeView');
treeview.dataBind(data);
```

}

But the dataBind does not work.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it to work.

Basically I created a model:

```
public class OrganizationUnitTreeViewModel
{
    public string Text { get; set; }

    public string Value { get; set; }

    public List<OrganizationUnitTreeViewModel> Items { get; set; }

    public bool Expanded = true;

    public bool LoadOnDemand = true;
}
```

Then in my action:

```
    public JsonResult Search(SearchModel model)
    {
        var request = OrganizationTreeSearchRequestCreate(model);
        var service = _ProductSetupService;
        var response = service.OrganizationTreeSearch(request);

        List<OrganizationUnitTreeViewModel> treeModelList = ConvertOrganizationUnitTree(response.Results);

        string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(treeModelList);

        return Json(json, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

Converting method creates model from hierarchical class structure:

```
private List<OrganizationUnitTreeViewModel> ConvertOrganizationUnitTree(List<OrganizationUnitTree> tree)
    {
        List<OrganizationUnitTreeViewModel> treeModelList = new List<OrganizationUnitTreeViewModel>();
        foreach (OrganizationUnitTree ou in tree)
        {
            OrganizationUnitTreeViewModel treeModel = new OrganizationUnitTreeViewModel();
            treeModel.Text = ou.OrganizationUnit.Name;
            treeModel.Value = ou.Id.ToString();
            if (ou.Subordinates != null && ou.Subordinates.Count > 0)
            {
                List<OrganizationUnitTreeViewModel> items = new List<OrganizationUnitTreeViewModel>();
                items.AddRange(ConvertOrganizationUnitTree(ou.Subordinates));
                treeModel.Items = items;
            }
            treeModelList.Add(treeModel);
        }
        return treeModelList;
    }
```

And at last but not least JS:

```
function ReloadTree(data) {
     var json = JSON.parse(data);
     var treeview = $('#OuTree').data('tTreeView');
     treeview.dataBind(json);}
```

That's all.
Hope that'll be of use to someone.